# Typelite Converts All Classes

Tags: typelite

I want to configure Typelite to only convert specific classes.

This is the TypeLite.tt:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="True" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)TypeLite.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)TypeLite.Net4.dll" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" #>
<#@ assembly name="$(TargetDir)Mydll.dll" #>

<#@ import namespace="TypeLite" #> 
<#@ import namespace="TypeLite.Net4" #> 
<#@output extension=".d.ts"#>

<#= TypeScript.Definitions()
        .For<Mydll.X.Y.Z>()
        %>
```

`Z` is a class, which is the only one I want converted to Typescript.

However, the output in TypeLite1.d.ts (TypeLite.d.ts is empty) is all the classes/enums/structs under `Mydll.X` namespace.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does `Z` reference these other classes?

Comment: @LukasKabrt Yeah, I later realized it was creating them. However, there were 4 classes not converted. Does the .d.ts file have a 10,000 lines limitation perhaps?

Comment: @LukasKabrt Also - is there a way to convert enums if I use specific declarations (`.For<...>()`) ?